# Squiz matrix migration from linux plesk panel running in two apache to aws

Tags: centos6.5

Can anyone help me with squiz matrix migration.? How to find out squiz database in the running server? There is no relevant docs explaining the same.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the database details for the running Squiz Matrix system by looking in data/private/conf/db.inc.

Squiz Matrix includes a script to generate a backup tarball. Details here:

https://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/server-administrator/chapters/backup-script

Your biggest issue will be making sure you've got all the prerequisites installed on the destination. There's another script to help you with that:

https://manuals.matrix.squizsuite.net/server-administrator/chapters/system-management-scripts#check_requirements.php